# Components condition on setup modify

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have a Basic MSI setup created with InstallShield 2015
It has one feature with two components, in the setup wizard I have a check box and its value is used as a condition of component2.

At first run the checkbox is cleared so component2 is not installed, now I run modify of the setup and a checked the checkbox and I expect that component2 will be installed but it doesn’t,
Component2 include some registry values and shortcuts and REINSTALLMODE value is omos

What am I doing wrong ?
How can I make component2 to be installed ?

Answer (score 0):

For your Component2 you would need to set flag to reevaluate condition.
[image]

Comment: It didn't helped, any other ideas?

Comment: How do you know it didn't work? If you just built the project with this setting and run it again in "upgrade" mode you would need to use "vomus" to re-cache your newly created package. Or you should uninstall completely the package and start the new package in "first time install" mode and then try to modify, as the system will cache your new package with fixed "reevaluate condition". Another thing is to monitor the log if your condition resolves to true.

Comment: I uninstalled the setup and than reinstalled and only then tried to modify, I checked the MSI log file and it look my condition is OK. maybe it's because the 2 components are on the same feature, I will check it.

Comment: It seems Reevaluate Condition works only on reinstall and not modify….

Comment: Yes, your last comment is correct, my bad, sorry. Please set REINSTALL property during modify for condition to be reevaluated. Ex: "REINSTALL=Feature1,Feature2,..."